# Linear independence of linear functionals on function space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I would like to show or verfiy the following

Here is my setting.

Let $F$ be a finite dimensional function space over the real $R$.

Let $L_1, L_2,\ldots,L_n$ be continuous linear functionals on $F$.

Then the following two are equivalent.

(a) For any $f\in F$, if $L_i(f)=0$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n$, then $f\equiv0$

(b) The set $\{L_i\}$ is linearly indepedent in the usual sense. That is, if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n \in R$ are such that $\alpha_1 L_1 + \alpha_2 L_2 + \cdots+\alpha_n L_n = \overrightarrow o $, then $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\cdots=\alpha_n = 0$, where $\overrightarrow o$ denotes the zero functional which maps every $f$ in $F$ to zero.

I have a "feeling" that this should be true, but despite my hours of efforts, I could not prove or disprove this.

Comment: I think condition $(a)$ is equivalent to saying $\{ L_1, \ldots, L_n \}$ spans the whole space of linear functionals on $F$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

The two conditions are not equivalent.

Firstly, suppose $L_1, \dots L_n$ satisfy condition (a). Then, every larger family of functionals $L_1, \dots, L_n, L_{n+1}, \dots, L_{n+k}$ satisfies condition (a). But this is not the case for (b), so (a) does not imply (b).

On the contrary, suppose $L_1, \dots L_n$ satisfy condition (b). Then every smaller family of functionals satisfies condition (b). But this is not the case for (a), so (b) does not imply (a).

Comment: If I further assume (as Michael Hardy suggested above) that the set of linear functionals span the whole space of linear functionals on F, then would the conditions be equivalent?

Comment: In that case the answer is yes. Micheal Hardy is true.

Comment: Do you mind showing the equivalence of the two properties under the additional assumption?

Comment: It's a quite long proof of linear algebra, and it's based on the assumption that $F$ is finite dimensional, so that $F^{**}$ is canonically isomorphic to $F$. Do you have familiarity with such geometric notions?